# How to include C files in Android gradle wihout using Android.mk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working with android app using ndk...

Latest android studio automatically generate Android.mk so i am using build.gradle to inculde c files..

but build.gradle only accept the header files from inside the project folder how to include header files from local storage like any path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the JNI sourceSet manually, see the [DSL reference](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html).

You can also set compilation flags, filter ABIs, choose STL variant, and more.

Comment: cppflags likes include header files from inside the project folder but i need include header files from outside of the project folder....

Comment: You can hardcode absolute paths if you really need, but e.g. `file("../lib/include").absolutePath` work fine; **`file`** in gradle is relative to the Module directory (where you have **build.gradle** file). You can use **`File`** which is relative to Project.